# meteor apps background data usage is excessive

Tags: android, meteor

I built a meteor android app with meteoric. In the last month after doing some meteor updates i noticed that my background data usage is excessive. Some days its almost 200 MB +. I am not sure whats changed. Is anyone else having this issue? Do you know whats causing it?

Answer (score 0):

I have not faced it yet, but maybe you can check your `subscriptions` in order to retrieve less data from server to client. I have found [this link](https://kadira.io/academy/reducing-pubsub-data-usage/) once, it might help you with it.

Basicaly, the author (of the great monitoring app Kadira) says we should optimize our subscriptions and fetchs from db. An example written by the author:

```
Meteor.publish('getTitles', function() {
    return Posts.find();
});
```

Here you are publishing something related to only titles, but is retrieving all data from posts, including content and comments (if any). To retrieve only titles and reduce a lot data consuming, would be enough to do like:

```
Meteor.publish('getTitles', function() {
    return Posts.find({}, {fields: {title: 1}});
});
```

You can find more on the post. But maybe this is a good way to start.

Comment: Hi.. thanks for the info.  I already implemented most of this. I also used smart subscriptions . When I actively use the app,  the data used is a  couple of megs. It's when the app is in the background that there is a massive spike in data usage. For instance last night between midnight and 6am the app consumed 80Mb. It's like there is a "data leak".

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Maybe you should post it on any of the official forums of Meteor, or even on Git Hub repo, to see if it is a bug or something.